# Migrating PL/SQL to EJB

Tags: java, spring, plsql

I am working on migration project from pl/sql to java. Here we are using spring with EJB.

While migrating the procedure we have a job scheduler. I failed to call the job from java. I have tried with the below code from spring

```
declare 
  J NUMBER;
  result varchar2(200);
begin
  result:=?||''''||?||''', '''||?||''', '''||?||''', '''||?||''', '''||?||''', '''||?||''', '''||?||''' ,'''||?||''', '''||?||''', '''||?||''', '''||?||''');'; 
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT( J , result , SYSDATE , NULL , FALSE,0,false ); 
  ?:=J;
END;
```

It's returning the value but internally it should execute the update query which is not happening. Can we execute like this from Java? Can some help me out?

Comment: DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT() requires a COMMIT.

Comment: thanks for the replay. even placing the commit also it's not working is it a correct way of calling the pl/SQL job from java?